# i am looking for a javascript server side template / page rendering engine

Tags: javascript, template-engine

Something like razor (MVC c#) but using javascript. What I actually want to do is to generate HTML reports from data. The scripting language I expose to the users is JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many JavaScript templating engines out there. Examples include:

- [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- [Dust](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)